# Can Apple Diagnostics be wrong about memory issue?

Tags: imac, memory, crash, kernel-panic

I am looking for a second opinion on an issue with my brand new iMac.

I purchased a new iMac direct from Apple about 3-4 weeks ago, and initially everything was fine. However, in the last few weeks I've been getting an increasing number of crashes (particularly with Safari, but others too), as well as a few kernel panics (usually from Parallels). As it happens most with these two, I've been troubleshooting them trying to find solutions.

After a particularly annoying crash yesterday, I decided to run the Apple Diagnostics tool (hold D on boot), which told me there was an error with the memory (codes PPM002, PPM003 and PPM004). I duly contacted Apple who've gone through the basic steps like removing startup items, resetting Safari, etc and was told to let them know if the problems persist. Fair enough, but they seem to have ignored the Apple Diagnostics result, which is confusing me.

My question is this; could the Apple Diagnostics tool be wrong? Is it possible, or even usual, for it to report errors where there are none? I'm concerned that Apple support will lead me on a week long search for software issues (and perhaps even temporarily solve it) when the diagnostics clearly say it is a hardware fault.
Thanks

Comment: Call them, you have Apple Care the first 3 months for free and they have to fix your iMac.

Comment: I did call them, but despite me mentioning the diagnostics result multiple times, they continued down the route of it being a software fault which is why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: the @Robuust must have missed your mentioning the contact with Apple already. As for Apple Diagnostics, run it again to see if you get same error.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Not really, I've searched for the error-code and the Apple way how to handle it (see answer below). They cannot just **do nothing** as they put it on their own site. Calling again should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm having the same problems PPM003 and PPM004 after several crashes, that doesn't let me boot my iMac (5K late 2014). Also got some kernel panics... Did they tell you what was the issue? What was the reparation about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4575) you have to [contact them](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE57).
They should be willing to help because you have Apple Care the first 90 days for free **and** they state it on the site theirselves:

[image]

Comment: After getting onto them a second time and persistently telling them about the error codes, they agreed it needed a repair. I got it to a local service provider who have confirmed that one of the modules was faulty.

Comment: Glad to hear this issue will be solved for you soon.